# Delete "Copy Always" file from bin directory of an ASP.NET web.application

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a project that has an xml file with "Copy to Output Directory" on "Copy Always". Now, this is good for our console applications that reference it, but is wrong for our ASP.NET application as it puts the file under root/bin.

How to automatically delete/exclude this file on "Publish" action of the ASP.NET application?

Using Visual Studio 2012.